# True/ false questions of basic concepts in topology

Tags: general-topology

Hi the following are only true or false questions and I'd appreciate if someone can help me to check if my answers are correct. Thanks :)

> (a) Any set of $X$ admits a metric such that the induced topology by the metric is Lindelof and connected
>
> (b) Any set $T_1$ space which is not $T_2$ it has a compact subset such that its closure is compact.
>
> (c) If $(X,\mathcal{T})$ is a topological space and $A,B\in \mathcal{P}(X)$. Then $\operatorname{fr}(A\cup B)=\operatorname{fr}(A)\cup \operatorname{fr}(B)$ whenever $\operatorname{Cl}(A)\cap B=\varnothing =A\cap\operatorname{Cl}(B)$
>
> (d) With the box topology any product of compact is compact.

**Answer**:

(a) No, suppose $X$ admits a metric such that is Lindelof and connected and also suppose that contains more than one point. Since $X$ is metrizable and Lindelof is second countable, so $\lvert X \rvert \le  \mathfrak{c}$. Now since $X$ is connected and completely regular the other inequality holds. Then $\lvert X \rvert =  \mathfrak{c}$. Hence, it is  not possible to find a metric for a set which does not have one or $\mathfrak{c}$ points such that makes the space Lindelof and connected.

(b) Since $X$ is a $T_1$ space the points are closed and clearly any finite set is closed. Then the topology is finer than the cofinite topology. Consider the subset $\{x\}$ for $x\in X$ so is compact and $\overline{\{x\}}=\{x\}$. Therefore its closure is compact. [Is necessary to assume that the space is not Hausdorff?]

(c) One direction of the equality is always true as: $$\operatorname{fr}(A\cup B)= (\overline A\cup \overline B)\cap \overline{X-(A\cup B)}=(\overline A \cap \overline{X-(A\cup B)}) \cup (\overline B \cap \overline{X-(A\cup B)})\subset (\overline A \cap \overline {X-A})\cup (\overline B\cap \overline{X-B})=\operatorname{fr}(A)\cup \operatorname{fr}(B)$$

Now suppose that $A,B$ are separated and $x\notin \operatorname{fr}(A\cup B)$. So either $x\notin \overline {A\cup B}=\overline A \cup \overline B$
or $x\notin \overline{X-(A\cup B)}$. In the first case clearly $x\notin \operatorname{fr}(A)\cup \operatorname{fr}(B)$. If $x\notin \overline{X-(A\cup B)}$, so $x\in X-\overline{X-(A\cup B)}=\operatorname{int}(A\cup B)$. Suppose that $x\in A$ since the sets are separated then $x\in X-\overline B$, it follows that $\operatorname{int} (A\cup B)-\overline B$ is a nbd of $x$. It is clear that $x\notin \operatorname{fr}(B)$. We shall show that also $x\notin \operatorname{fr}(A)$. To the contrary, if $x \in \operatorname{fr}(A)$, thus

$$\varnothing\not=(\operatorname{int} (A\cup B)-\overline B)\cap {X- A}\subset ((A\cup B)-\overline B)\cap X-A\subset A\cap X- A=\varnothing$$

Contradiction. Then $x\notin \operatorname{fr}(A)$ and $x\notin \operatorname{fr}(B)$, i.e., $x\notin \operatorname{fr}(A)\cup \operatorname{fr}(B)$. The other case is similar.

(d) No, consider the product $\{0,1\}^{\bf{N}}$ in the box topology. For each $x\in \{0,1\}^{\bf{N}}$, $x$ is the unique member of the open set determined by its coordinates. Then the product is discrete and infinite and so, cannot be compact even though the discrete space $\{0,1\}$ is compact.

Comment: Hi @ThomasE. in the other inclusion of $(c)$ I was trying to argue by contraposition, assuming that $A,B$ are separated we need to show  $\operatorname{fr}(A)\cup \operatorname{fr}(B)\subset \operatorname{fr}(A\cup B)$ and is equivalent to say that if $x\notin \operatorname{fr}(A\cup B)$ then $x\notin \operatorname{fr}(A)\cup \operatorname{fr}(B)$

Comment: Yes, it’s all correct, and no, in (b) you don’t need to assume that the space is not Hausdorff.

Comment: @BrianM.Scott Thank you, it's a pleasure to see you again in mathstack.

Comment: You’re welcome (and thank *you*).